# Modify array with jQuery to get sequenced indexes

Tags: jquery, arrays, google-maps-api-3, indexing

This javascript array contains coordinates that I send to Google Maps API to draw a path in the map. **Sometimes** coordinates[0] is empty because it depends on a previous route that might exist or not (using Google Maps).

This is my code:

```
coordinates = [];
```

(between here I look for a previous path (coordinates[0]). In this case we are asuming that it is null. So we have these values:

```
coordinates[1] = '50,20'; //route 1
coordinates[2] = '10,18'; //route 2
coordinates[3] = '27,34'; //route 3
```

After that, I draw the path in the map like this:

```
travel_path = new google.maps.Polyline({
  path: coordinates
});
travel_path.setMap(map);
```

The problem: When there is **no** coordinates[0] (that happens when there is no previous segment of the travel path) the .Polyline method throws an error because it needs to receive an array with sequenced indexes starting from 0.

The question: How can I convert my original array to this (compare indexes):

```
coordinates[0] = '50,20'; //route 1
coordinates[1] = '10,18'; //route 2
coordinates[2] = '27,34'; //route 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`coordinates.shift()` removes the first element from the array.

```
var coordinates = [];
//coordinates[0] = undefined;
coordinates[1] = '50,20'; //route 1
coordinates[2] = '10,18'; //route 2
coordinates[3] = '27,34'; //route 3
coordinates.shift();
```

`coordinates.shift()` causes this to happen:

```
coordinates[0] = coordinates[1];
coordinates[1] = coordinates[2];
coordinates[2] = coordinates[3];
//coordinates[3] is removed.
```

Answer (score 1):

Like rob said, use shift(), you can do a check to see if coordinates[0] is undefined first.

```
if( !coordinates[0] )
    coordinates.shift();
```

Comment: if(typeof coordinates[0]=='undefined') coordinates.shift();

Comment: `!coordinates[0]` does the same thing, and it's shorter :-P

Comment: You missed the point. It does not do the same thing. What about coordinates[0]=0?

Comment: There wouldn't be a coordinate 0, because it's a string! Infact it's x and y coordinates so it wouldn't be 0. It has to be a string in order to get both coordinates x and y.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Slice):

```
coordinates.slice(1);
```

**[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/QcEp6/)**.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
travel_path = new google.maps.Polyline({
  path:(function(){
        var arrayCoord=[],k=0;
        for(var key in coordinates){
            arrayCoord[k]=coordinates[key];
            ++k;
        }
        return arrayCoord;
  })()
});
travel_path.setMap(map);
```